# Upper and lower bounds for the sum of the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{c_n}{(x+1)^n}$, $x\geq0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to find tight upper and lower bounds for the sum $S(x)$ of the following series of functions:

$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{c_n}{(x+1)^n},\qquad x\geq0,
$$

where $c_n$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, $0\leq c_n\leq1$ for every $n\geq1$, and asymptotically $c_n\sim n^{-\frac{d}{2}}$, and $d$ is a positive integer.

Notice that, if $d\geq3$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges poitwise on the whole $[0,+\infty[$, and hence $S(x)$ is well defined on the whole $[0,+\infty[$ for these values of $d$; otherwise ($d=1,2$), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges only on $]0,+\infty[$.

Moreover, notice that, if $d\geq3$, the just mentioned pointwise convergence is total (hence uniform) on $[0,+\infty[$, while if $d=1,2$, it is total just on every $[\epsilon,+\infty[$, $\epsilon>0$.

Any suggestions on how I could proceed?

Comment: Does it help that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{d/2} }}\frac{1}{{(x + 1)^n }}}  = \operatorname{Li}_{d/2} \left( {\frac{1}{{x + 1}}} \right)
$$ where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the polylogarithm?

Comment: I am not so familiar with the polylogarithm, trying to get to know it a bit. Thank you. The problem is that I just know that $c_n\sim n^{-d/2}$, so i guess this problem in general boils down to find upper and lower bounds for $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{d/2}}\frac{1}{(x+1)^n}$

Comment: You can say that $$
\frac{m}{{n^{d/2} }} \le c_n  \le \frac{M}{{n^{d/2} }}
$$ if that is enough.